# How to use wxpython in an ipython notebook or console

Tags: python, wxpython, anaconda

I am using the anaconda python distribution (python version 2.7) and I would like to be able to use wxpython either in a notebook or at least in an ipython console through the anaconda spyder app (their IDE). I am running into what is apparently a common problem which is due to the anaconda python environment not being recognized as a framework with GUI access.

In fact, I am able to launch a wxpython app when working directly in ipython when launched from the command line. However, when trying to get an app to run from either the spyder IDE ipython console or an ipython notebook I get this error:

`This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.`

If anyone knows a workaround for this I would very much appreciate your advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In an ipython notebook before you run a cell invoking wxpython functions you have to insert the `%gui` magic:

`%gui wx`

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I tried it and I get the same error now just when running the %gui wx function. It kills the kernel too... What setup are you using that allows you run wxpython in a notebook?

Comment: Anaconda distribution with Python 2.7.9.

Comment: Are you running it from the root environment? Did you do anything to modify pythonpath?

Comment: Ok, here's a weird observation. If I start a notebook and use `%gui wx` I get the error message and it crashes the kernel. If I use another backend, e.g. `%gui qt`, it works fine. If I then run `%gui` without any arguments to disable any backends followed by calling `%gui wx` everything works completely fine. Strangely, if you restart the kernel and first run `%gui` then run `%gui wx`, it still crashes. It seems like you have to first set the backend to something other than wx, then turn off gui backends with `%gui`, then you can run `%gui wx` with no problems. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I believe simply using python**w** vs. python helped when I was using a MacBook.